# NGRAM doesn't work in Elasticsearch Rails

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have a table which has job_title field,

I want to make a fuzzy search let user can still get the result when they mis-spell query keyword.

For example, I have many records have the "Android developer" as its job_title,

When the user issues the incorrect search `Job.es_qsearch("Andoirddd")`, it should work as well by the help of `NGRAM_ANALYZER`

However, I could get any results from the incorrect keyword.

I can only get the result when I type `Job.es_qsearch("Android")`

How could I achieve the search result as I expect.

Thanks

## job.rb

```
NGRAM_ANALYZER = {analysis: {
       filter: {
          autocomplete_filter: {
             type: "edge_ngram",
             min_gram: 3,
             max_gram: 20
          }
       },
       analyzer: {
          ngram_analyzer: {
             type: :custom,
             tokenizer: :standard,
             filter: [
                :lowercase,
                :autocomplete_filter
             ]
          }
       }
    }}

settings NGRAM_ANALYZER do
    mappings do
      indexes :job_title, include_in_all: 'ngram_analyzer'
      indexes :description, include_in_all: 'ngram_analyzer'
    end
end


def self.es_qsearch(*args, &block)
 q_params = {
        multi_match: {
          query: "*#{args}*",
          fields: ['job_title^5', 'description']
        }
      }

  __elasticsearch__.search(
    {
      query: q_params,
    }
  )
end
```

## I used Fuzzy Query but it's still not working

### Fuzzy Query sent this query to ES search

```
{:index=>"jobs",
   :type=>"job",
   :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:fuzzy=>{:description=>{:value=>["electrical"], :fuzziness=>2}}}]}}, :size=>200}},
```

### Fuzzy Query 1: not working

```
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
              "fuzzy": {
                "description": {
                    # min_similarity: 0.4,
                    "value": args,
                    # prefix_length: 0,
                    "fuzziness": 2
                }
              },
            }]
        }
```

### Fuzzy Query 1: not working

```
        "fuzzy": {
          "description": {
              # min_similarity: 0.4,
              "value": args,
              # prefix_length: 0,
              "fuzziness": 2
          }
        },
```

Comment: By default the search query will try to match the search term with `ngram` tokens. Since there won't be any token as  `Andoirddd` the result will fail. So try by adding a `search_analyzer` as ngram analyzer. else add `fuzzy` in search query.

Comment: @ArunPrakash it's no lucky, pls take a look my update. thank you